# Need to read into an ArrayList and separate Positive and Negative numbers

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

I need to read in 10 integers into an `ArrayList` and then have to program sort them into two groups: "Positive Integers" and "Negative Integers".

I have two `ArrayList`s and an if statement to determine where each integer should go, however I do not know what variable to use in order to make this work. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sort {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Integer> neg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      int i=0 ;

      while(i <= 10) {
          System.out.println("enter an integer");
          if(??? < 0) {  //here is where my question is
              neg.add(sc.nextInt());
          } else {
              pos.add(sc.nextInt());
          }

          i++;  
      }
      System.out.println("positive numbers" + pos);
      System.out.println("negative numbers" + neg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while(i<=10){
    System.out.println("enter an integer");
    int next_int = sc.nextInt();
    if(next_int < 0) {  //here is where my question is
        neg.add(next_int);
    } else {
        pos.add(next_int);
    }

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int number = sc.nextInt()
if(number<0){
    neg.add(sc.nextInt());
}
else{
    pos.add(sc.nextInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigable set.. Add the numbers to it and then just query for the head or tail by passing 0 as the argument. Let me know if you want me to elaborate.

Comment: It's a Set and won't support double entries. If someone enters "1" twice then "1" will only occur once in the output, in stead of twice. That may not be wat the user wants :)

Comment: Well, I agree, although depending upon the use case another variation, navigable map can be used. The advantage is that the data structure encapsulates the user logic of storing the data and also reduces the branching in the user code.